# How to set an image into an NSCollectionView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift3, nscollectionview

Below is my code:

```
var  arrCategory:[NSString] =
         ["Australia","Austria","Belgium","Brazil","Cameroon","Canada","Chile","China","Denmark","Argentina"]
```

The strings given in above array are the name of images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Replace your code with:**

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "\(self.arrCategory[indexPath.row]).png")
cell.LblName.text = "\(self.arrCategory[indexPath.row])"
```

Comment: Replace `NSImage` by `UIImage`?

Comment: not possible in macapp.MacApp in only uses NSImage and your ans not usefull for me i send this code for mac application development.

Comment: yes you can use cell.imageView?.image =  NSImage(named:"\(self.arrCategory[indexPath.row]).png") if you use NSImageView.

Comment: this not work not getting any image on my cell. if u possible than give me your some id i l send my code and help me out in collection view ...

Answer (score 1):

My Question Of Answer i find out and is Here:

```
cell.imgView.image = NSImage(named:self.arrCategory[indexPath.item])
cell.lbl.stringValue =  arrlbl[indexPath.item] as String
```